# ASPNET core Razor, Fontawesome 4.7 missing in lib after download

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, font-awesome, bower

I have been trying out VS2017 ASP.NET core Razor lately, and trying to download fontawesome 4.7 (latest as of today) using bower.

However, after downloading font-awesome, I can't find it in the wwwroot/lib.

Must I update the gulp to compile the less to css and the copy it to the lib folder myself? I don't feel this is the correct way, otherwise the font-awesome folder will remains even after we uninstall it from bower.

I really don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

I fond out that this might be a bug in VS2017

While we can manage bower packages out of the box. We need to add bower.json to the root of the solution manually. Otherwise bower will not work.